# Did I take the survey?

Tags: support, survey-2020

I *think* I've already taken the 2020 survey but I'm just not sure (been distracted lately). Is there a way of knowing if I in fact already did take it? As far as I can tell the site lets me take it, but I don't know if any check is in place to ensure that it is not taken twice.

Comment: They save it in a cookie and if you have that cookie set you're told you've already taken it. Obviously that only works if you check with the same browser you think you used and haven't cleared them since.

Comment: You haven't earned the badge on SO. But you could have chosen to earn the badge in a different site, or not to earn the badge at all.

Comment: So I started to take it and halfway through I am now convinced I already did take it. Not sure why I have no cookie and no badge though. Anyway, thanks!